# Any Mailjet API for add dynamic Domain or Sender Email?

Tags: node.js, mailjet

Any Mailjet API for add dynamic Domain or Sender Email ?

I need to add dynamic sender email/ domain. Is there any api for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can authorize all email addresses for specific domain using a catch-all expression like "*@yourdomain.com" as "Email". See here:
https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?javascript#create-a-new-dns-entry

Comment: Thanks bro, 
by default its in "inactive" state, we neeed to validate that entry with following validate api?
[https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?javascript#validate-sender-and-domain]

Comment: Yes, To start the validation, you can call the validate action on the /sender resource. Once you add the .txt file at the root of the domain, you can activate the sender - https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?javascript#validate-sender-and-domain

Comment: Also, there is an alternative using DNS TXT record validation, which might be even more convenient for you. The process is described in the same section - https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#validate-sender-and-domain